# C# MVC4 Linq - Filter table by either date or date + time

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, linq-to-entities

I have a table containing several columns which I search by column + a user entered string in order to filter the results. However I'm having trouble getting my DateTime column to filter correctly (the rest all work). I can show results of an exact match, but not if the user enters just a date with no time I get no results.

Expected results are if a user enters 14/08 or 14/08/2014 or 14/08/2014 12:56:32 all results matching this entered date or date and time should display.

My Linq

```
var filterresults = from m in db.cd_CleardownCore
                            select m;
```

My Filter Attempt 1: (Exact match only < Works)

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(searchString);
string strDate = datetime.ToShortDateString();

filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.TimeStarted == datetime)
```

My Filter Attempt 2: (Checking if column contains date < doesn't currently Work)

```
filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.TimeStarted.ToString().Contains(strDate));
```

So could someone explain why attempt 2 does not work? or could suggest a solution? 
+ if i can provide anything to make it clearer just let me know.

Comment: Just curious why you are doing a contains versus startswith. But if I were you the way I would debug this, is to see what TimeStarted.ToString() gives you. and that would give you an idea of what is wrong

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx it says that a date.ToString() returns the date and time in the current culture format. Is it possible that this means that your TimeStarted.ToString() is returning "08/14/2014"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two queries for that:

First check if the `datetime` object has time other than `00:00:00` that means that some time part is specified, in that case you need exact comparison, otherwise compare the field for passed date range like:

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(searchString);
if (datetime.TimeOfDay != TimeSpan.Zero) //comparison with 00:00:00 time
{
    filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.TimeStarted == datetime);
}
else
{
    DateTime plusOneDateTime = datetime.AddDays(1).Date;
    filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.TimeStarted >= datetime.Date 
                                           && x.TimeStarted < plusOneDateTime);
}
```

The reason your queries are failing is because `ToString` usage in LINQ to entities would fail since there is no translation available from LINQ expression to underlying data source language *(SQL)*.

Also remember that chances are your comparison with exact time may not return any results, since `searchString` might not contain the precise time as stored in the database. In that case you can resort to range checking for hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: +1. The range approach is spot on.  To clarify the final point about about precision, I would suggest to the OP that instead of the exact match shown in the first part, you should put more work into determining the start and end points of the query range based on the input given.  For example, if the user gave a value of `14/08/2014 12:56`, then the query should run from `14/08/2014 12:56:00` (inclusive) to `14/08/2014 12:57:00` (exclusive).

Comment: Also - watch out for culture differences.  Parsing with `Convert.ToDateTime` without providing a culture will use the *current* culture - which may or may not align with the user's culture.  Consider the user may enter `"01/02/2014"` and you need to know for certain whether that's Feb 1st or Jan 2nd.

Comment: Thank you Habib the code works as I intended in the project and your explanation was good. An also thankyou Matt this has given me some thought about how the project can be improved as catering for culture will be important in the final version.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime matches are going to be tricky, since you accept a wide array of inputs.

If the format is more or less fixed, you can probably get away with string matching.

So assuming you always accept in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS, you can try

`filterresults = filterresults.ToArray().Where(x => x.TimeStarted.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss").IndexOf(strDate) > -1));`

What you're essentially doing here is normalizing your comparison base and since data and time have different delimiters, a simple substring check can give you correct results.

So assuming that `TimeStarted` is `14/08/2014 12:56:32`:

```
"14/08/2014 12:56:32".IndexOf("14/08") // matches
"14/08/2014 12:56:32".IndexOf("14/08/2014") // matches
"14/08/2014 12:56:32".IndexOf("14/08/2014 12:56:32") // matches
```

This logic will work as long as people search for parts of date in order like:

DD
DD/MM
DD/MM/YYYY

and so on.

It may be ambiguous if user enters 09 and 09 means both day or month. But if your UI always goes by the rule the first 2 are day, second 2 are month, next 4 are year and so on, then you'd be fine.

Also note that I'm doing a `ToArray` since Linq2Entities doesn't understand `ToString`.

Comment: The `ToArray` is going to pull down the entire table and filter in memory, and the format string you gave is not valid in C#.

Comment: Fixed the format string. And yes, this will bring down the entire table, but again, whether its a acceptable or unacceptable thing depends on OP's situation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare the date part -- so do that:

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(searchString);


filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.TimeStarted.Date == datetime.Date)
```

You could also use `ToString("d")` but that is not needed.